# What are the advantages of UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY and INSERT DELAYED INTO?

Tags: mysql

I was going through some code and noticed that `UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY` and `INSERT DELAYED INTO` are used for updating the database. What is is the use of these statements? Should I use these in every insert and update statement for various tables in the same database?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With the [LOW_PRIORITY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html) keyword, execution of the UPDATE is delayed until no other clients are reading from the table. Normally, reading clients are put on hold until the update query is done. If you want to give the reading clients priority over the update query, you should use LOW_PRIORITY.

The [DELAYED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-delayed.html) option for the INSERT statement is a MySQL extension to standard SQL that is very useful if you have clients that cannot or need not wait for the INSERT to complete. This is a common situation when you use MySQL for logging and you also periodically run SELECT and UPDATE statements that take a long time to complete.

Comment: Also note: As of MySQL 5.6.6, INSERT DELAYED is deprecated, and removed in 5.7

Answer (score 11):

`LOW_PRIORITY`, `HIGH_PRIORITY` and `DELAYED` are only useful in a few circustamces. If you don't have a BIG load they can't help you. If you have, don't do anything you don't fully understand.

All of these otpions only work with MyISAM, not InnoDB, not views.

`DELAYED` doesn't work with partitioned tables, and it's clearly designed for dataware house. The client sends the insert and then forgets it, without waiting for the result. So you won't know if the insert succeded, if there were duplicate values, etc. It should never be used while other threads could `SELECT` from that table, because an insert delayed is never concurrent.

`LOW_PRIORITY` waits until NO client is accessing the table. But if you have a high traffic, you may wait until the connection times out... that's not what you want, I suppose :)

Also, note that `DELAYED` will be removed in Oracle MySQL 5.7 (but not in MariaDB).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use these, then you have a big load on your server, and you know that some UPDATE or INSERT statements are not high priority and they can act on load.

Example: SQL that generates some statistics or items top. They are slow, and do not need to be executed immediately.

Comment: I'm trying to work out whether *now* is a typo for *not*. In fact, I can barely understand this answer at all. I also don't know what "Exp." is an abbreviation of.

Answer (score -2):

If your UPDATEs on MySQL a read intensive environment are taking as much as 1800 seconds then it is advisable to use the UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY.

Comment: Why 1800 seconds? You could have explained your reasoning.

Comment: @Dharma was talking about _[wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)_ and _[interactive_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout)_ system variables that depends on client's _CLIENT_INTERACTIVE_ flag. However, default value of these variables is 28800 (8hrs) and not 1800.