# PHP - Best practice for storing page view in database

Tags: php, mysql, view, counter, increment

May I know what's the best practice for storing page views in database?

Is it costly to update the pageview value every time the page is loaded?

And is there any possible errors/threats while updating the pageview and in the same time, someone else is modifying the same row's data?

For e.g.

Table - Item
ID
Name
Description
PageView

I understand it might not be a very big issue, it can apply to some other data that updates very often, would like to know what's the best approach of doing it. 
The possible scenario that came into my mind was, if there's a lot of pages is running in the simultaneously. Will there be any performance issue?

Pardon my English, and many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Google Analytics not an option for you?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234972/advantages-of-update-low-priority-and-insert-delayed-into

Comment: @TomFielder, I need the pageview to be shown on each page when it's loaded. I'm not sure if Google Analytics can do that.

Comment: You probably can do it using the Google Analytics API - but it wouldn't be an ideal solution to what you're wanting to do :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best approach is to write a new line into the table for every view, rather than to keep a rolling tally which could lead to locking problems on a large system.  For additional performance, you can add rows using `INSERT DELAYED` syntax. This will allow the DB handle to return immediately and your script won't wait for the insert to complete. Documentation here:-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html

It might also be worth looking at the Archive storage engine which is aimed specifically at this type of logging.  You can only `INSERT` and `SELECT` data but performance is aimed at rapid writing.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/archive-storage-engine.html

To view pageview information you simply query the number of rows for any given page. A major advantage of this approach is that by logging a timestamp with every page view, you can analyse data by time of day, days of week etc. and see what shape your traffic is.

Comment: Thank you @Purpletoucan for your answers, appreciate it. Will read them up, and see if any of them fits what I needed.